# Split perfect and Cantor sets

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Let $C$ be a  Cantor ternary set. We can write it  as union of $\mathfrak{c}$ many disjoint Cantor  sets as follows: 
$$ C\times C= \bigcup_{x\in C} (\{x\}\times C)$$ and clearly $\{x\}\times C$ is Cantor set. Moreover, $(\{x\}\times C) \bigcap (\{y\}\times C)=\emptyset$. So, we can define a homemorhpic  between $C$ and $C\times C$ in the natural way just by sending $x$ to $\{x\}\times C$. We can conclude that $C=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}} C_{\alpha}$ where $C_{\alpha}$'s are pairwise disjoint Cantor set.  I have two questions. Kindly check if what I did is correct and Also I know the same fact is correct for perfect, that is, every perfect set can be written as union of $\mathfrak{c}$-many  pairwise disjoint perfect sets.

Comment: I don't understand how you can send $x$ to $\{x\}\times C$. Note that $\{x\}\times C$ is a *subset* of $C\times C$, not an element of it. One way to build such a homeomorphism is to first identify $C$ with $2^\omega$(the space of infinite $0,1$ sequences) and then prove $2^\omega \cong 2^\omega \times 2^\omega$ via the map that splits each sequence to it's two odd and even indexed subsequences.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Yes you are right, I can fix that but how perfect set how this can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you defined (at least before any edits you might make after I first posted my answer) is NOT a homeomorphism. Indeed, it’s clearly not an injective function. I’ll prove the result for perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$ (similar proofs can be used to prove the result for perfect subsets of ${\mathbb R}^n),$ and I’ll leave it to you or others for generalizations to an arbitrary metric space or beyond.

**Theorem:** Let $P$ be a nonempty perfect subset of ${\mathbb R}.$ Then $P$ contains $c$-many pairwise disjoint nowhere dense perfect subsets.

**Proof 1:** First, map $P$ continuously onto $[0,1].$ For intervals this is trivial; for Cantor sets use a monotone increasing function similar to the Cantor function; if both types appear, pick one and work within that subset. Then follow this with a continuous mapping of $[0,1]$ onto the unit square (use a Peano curve). Now observe that the inverse images of the vertical fibers $\{r\} \times [0,1],$ as $r$ varies over $[0,1],$ gives continuum many pairwise disjoint nowhere dense perfect subsets of the given perfect set.

**Proof 2:** Since $P$ contains a nonempty compact perfect nowhere dense set (simply carry out a Cantor set type construction process relativized to $P),$ without loss of generality we can assume that $P$ is a nonempty compact perfect nowhere dense set. Since $P$ and $P \times P$ are nonempty totally disconnected perfect compact metric spaces, it follows from a classical topological result that $P$ is homeomorphic to $P \times P$ [Willard’s [**General Topology**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486434796), Corollary 30.4, p. 217]. Hence, the inverse images of $\{x \} \times P$ for any fixed homeomorphism from $P$ onto $P \times P,$ as $x$ varies over $P,$ gives $c$-many pairwise disjoint perfect subsets of $P.$

The result itself is due to Mahlo (1913) **[1]** and the first proof above is due to Luzin/Sierpiński (1917) **[2]**.

**[1]** Friedrich Paul Mahlo, [*Über teilmengen des kontinuums von dessen mächtigkeit*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101043820529&view=1up&seq=323) [On subsets of the continuum with its power], **Berichte über die Verhandlungen der Königlich Sächsischen Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Leipzig, Mathematisch-Physische Klasse** 65 (1913), 283-315.

**[2]** Nikolai Nikolaevich Luzin [Lusin] and Wacław Franciszek Sierpiński, [*Sur une propriété du continu*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3118k/f498.image) [On a property of the continuum], **Comptes Rendus Hebdomadaires des Séances de l’Académie des Sciences** (Paris) 165 #16 (15 October 1917), 498-500.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you so much for your time. On small thing , if $P$ is nowhere dense compact set, how should we do

Comment: In the case of the first proof, map continuously onto $[0,1]$ using a monotone increasing function similar to the Cantor function, followed by a Peano curve onto $[0,1]^2$ (which is continuous). The composition of these two functions is a continuous function from the perfect set **onto** $[0,1]^2,$ and the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed, and each of the sets $\{r\} \times [0,1]$ is closed in $[0,1]^2.$ Think about details such as this a bit to get the rest of what you want.

Comment: I have one question about your second proof. How can you assume that $P$ is none-empty compact nowhere dense set? I know that any perfect $P$ contains such a set, but how do you deal with the remaining part of $P$? In other words, let $C \subseteq P$ be a copy of the Cantor set, how do you deal with $P - C$?

Comment: For example how do you split $P = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In the theorem I simply stated that $P$ **contains** $c$-many pairwise disjoint perfect sets [#]. I didn't claim that $P$ is **partitioned** into $c$-many pairwise disjoint perfect sets. ([#] In case you think I overlooked that this wording allows for the empty set to be one of the perfect sets, note that there will still be $c$-many nonempty perfect sets.) It is true that you can get $P$ partitioned into $c$-many perfect sets, and I first stated it this way, but I was in a hurry (I've been working on something else the whole time) and didn't I want to deal with all the extra details.

Comment: For the "partitioned" version, I suppose one way would be to first prove a structure result for perfect subsets of the reals, whereby each perfect set consists of a disjoint union of countably many compact intervals and countably many compact perfect nowhere dense sets, each type interlaced with the other type. There is probably a more sophisticated and elegant approach, because I know the result is true in higher dimensions and it would be a mess to prove such versions the "brute force" way, and I'm pretty sure I've never seen the kind of mess I'm thinking of in a book or paper.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the "structure result" I implied is correct, as I'm now thinking of situations in which relatively tiny closed intervals are included in lots of the complementary intervals of the Cantor set, such as in every other complementary interval at each of the odd-numbered construction stages, or something equally difficult to imagine as being Cantor sets interlaced between closed intervals. Nonetheless, I think something like this is true and can be proved in a way similar to how one proves every open set of reals is a countable pairwise disjoint union of open intervals.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri [Bankston & McGovern (1979), Theorem 1.14](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~paulb/Paper/toppart.pdf) proved that $\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof, thanks for the reference. Nice paper in general.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Do you have the second paper in English?

Comment: @00GB: I don't have an English translation of either paper. I don't think any of the many 1910s and 1920s point set theory (classical descriptive set theory) papers have been translated except for Suslin's 1917 paper on analytic sets. (I spent several days in June 2007 preparing a translation of this, with the help of someone because I can only "read" French slowly with a dictionary.)