# Another way for partition of perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, axioms, descriptive-set-theory, transfinite-induction

Let $P$ be a perfect $P\subset\Bbb R.$ Then there exists a family $\{P_{\alpha}\subset P\colon \alpha<\mathfrak c\}$ of pairwise disjoint perfect subsets such that $$P=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mathfrak c} P_{\alpha}.$$ This is a well known result. The proof will rely on the following two theorems:

**Theorem** $1$. Let $X$ be a nonempty perfect Polish space. Then there is an embedding of $C$ (Cantor set) into $X.$

**Theorem** $2$. Let $C$ be a Cantor set. Then, $$C\cong C\times C=\bigcup_{x\in C} \Big(\{x\}\times C\Big)$$

**Edit**: I thought it would be clear to get from the above Theorems but this is not the case even for me. Here what I got. Theorem 1 gives me, there is a map $f\colon C\to X$  establishing $C\cong f[C]\subset X.$ Let $P\subset X$ be a perfect$\subset X.$ Then it is polish space in itself. So, we can apply the Theorem 1. for a Cantor set $C'$ so there is map $g\colon C'\to P$ such that a $$\bigcup_{x\in C'} \Big(\{x\}\times C'\Big)\cong g[C']\subset P$$ Now, this give us that $P$ contains continuum many pairwise disjoint perfect set. But How can we get equality? Any idea? In addition, is there any direct proof without using these Theorems?

Comment: This reference may be helpful: http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~paulb/Paper/toppart.pdf

Comment: @bof, I edited my answer. I think it is still not clear even for me

Comment: Closely related earlier posted question: [Split perfect and Cantor sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3567918/13130). The present question asks about an unresolved issue in that earlier question/answer/comment thread.

Comment: Dave L Renfro , but what was written there as I did but how equality can be hold. Any idea ?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Maybe equality need not behold for any  perfect set. what do you think ?

Comment: I don't know off-hand right now (busy with many very different things now . . .), but I included my earlier comment to make it clear that your current question involves a specific issue that was not resolved in that earlier question.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I see thank you very much

Comment: Brian M. Scott, This question has been unresolved for the old post. So, it would be great if you could share your thought about even by saying this might not be true for all perfect sets.

Comment: By Theorem 1.14 of [Bankston & McGovern](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/~paulb/Paper/toppart.pdf), any interval of the real line (with or without endpoints) can be partitioned into Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof, Thank you fo getting back to me.  However, this  only showed for closed interval which is perfect but not for every perfect set.

Comment: I believe the same argument works (as is claimed in the paper) for an open or half-open interval. Moreover, I believe that any perfect subset of $\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into countably many subsets, where each subset is either an interval (open, closed, or half-open) or a Cantor set.

Comment: @bof, sorry this is not correct. think about Cantor set contains no interval. I will try  an answer for what I believe this the case.

Comment: The statement "each subset is either an interval or a Cantor set" is true if they are all Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof: In the Bankston/McGovern paper, I think Theorem 1.15(i) -- for the case $\sigma({\bf C}, \, {\bf C})$ and the cardinal $c$ -- implies that any nonempty nowhere dense perfect subset of the reals can be written as a union of continuum many pairwise disjoint nowhere dense perfect subsets of the real line. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, I believe you're right. What's your point? Did I say something to the contrary? Am I missing something?

Comment: @bof: Nothing wrong that I can tell. About an hour ago I saw your comment about Theorem 1.14, and your additional comment about open and half-open intervals. This led me to look at the paper a bit (something I didn't have a chance to do yesterday -- you had then already previously mentioned the paper -- when I wrote my earlier comments) to see whether the specific issue at hand is in there somewhere. It seems the OP issue is contained in Theorem 1.15(i), but since you didn't mention Theorem 1.15(i), I wasn't sure whether you hadn't noticed it's relevance or whether I was overlooking something.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I understood the OP's question to be about perfect sets in general; *nowhere dense* perfect sets are easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definitions.** $\mathbb R$ is the real line. A subset of $\mathbb R$ is an *interval* if it's connected and has more than one point, a *perfect set* if it's a nonempty closed set with no isolated points, a *Cantor set* if it's homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set $C$.

**Lemma.** Every perfect set $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into subsets each of which is either an interval or a Cantor set.

**Proof.** Let $Y$ be the union of all sets of the form $U\cap X$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and $U\cap X$ is connected, and let $Z=X\setminus Y$. (Either $Y$ or $Z$ may be empty.)

Note that $Y$ can be partitioned into intervals; namely, each component of $Y$ is an interval.

Note that $Z$ is a totally disconnected closed set with no isolated points. If $Z$ is nonempty and compact, then $Z$ is a Cantor set; if $Z$ is not compact, $Z$ can be partitioned into countably many Cantor sets. In either case, $Z$ can be partitioned into Cantor sets.

**Theorem.** Every perfect set $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$ Cantor sets.

**Proof.** By the lemma $X$ can be partitioned, if not into Cantor sets, then at least into Cantor sets and intervals. However, by Theorem 1.14 (and the first sentence of the proof) of Paul Bankston and Richard J. McGovern, Topological partitions, General Topology and its Applications 10 (1979), 215–229 ([pdf](http://www.mscs.mu.edu/%7Epaulb/Paper/toppart.pdf)), each interval can be partitioned into Cantor sets. Hence $X$ can be partitioned into Cantor sets. Since a Cantor set can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$ Cantor sets, it follows that $X$ can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$ Cantor sets.

Comment: bof, what is $P$ in the proof of the lemma

Comment: big,  I will read tomorrow it and get back to you in case I have question.

Comment: bof, Is there any reference for the Lemma or this your idea. I agree,  your looks correct to me. I am still confused with exercise that I mentioned. Thank you again

Comment: I don't know if there's a reference for the lemma. I just made it up for my answer to your question. There's nothing wrong with the exercise you mentioned. The theorem of Bankston & McGovern which I used is not well known, and the proof is somewhat tricky. No doubt one can give a simpler proof using the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: bof, I checked the proof and it seems okay to me. But one more things, in my answer, peherps I was not clear I was trying to say that Can perfect be partitioned in ZFC into continuum many perfect sets which are not Cantor set. Maybe no one cares about if the perfect set Cantor or not.

Comment: @00GB Can every perfect set be partitioned into perfect sets which are not Cantor sets? Is that what you're asking? The answer is no. The Cantor set is a counterexample. The Cantor set is a perfect set, but the Cantor set can not be partitioned into perfect sets which are not Cantor sets, because every perfect subset of the Cantor set is a Cantor set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that I mentioned in OP wouldn't behold for a perfect set in ZFC by the following exercise, see fundamentals of real analysis by James Foran, exercise $13$ page $127.$

**Exercise**: Prove that the continuum hypothesis implies that each perfect set subset of the real line can be written as the union of $\omega_1$ pairwise disjoint non-empty perfect sets.

If OP is correct for every perfect set so the above exercise has no meaning since $\omega_1=\mathfrak c.$

Is that correct? Please share your thought. Thank you all.

Comment: Dave L. Renfro , I added an answer that shows the equality need not behold in ZFC

Comment: bof, see the answer now

Comment: The continuum hypothesis makes things easy. By Theorem 1.12(ii) of Bankston & McGovern, assuming Martin's axiom (weaker than the continuum hypothesis), every Polish space without isolated points can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$ Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof, This shows the fact in OP might not be true in ZFC.

Comment: Noah Scweber, even though this seems a very simple fact but I got confused. Please if you have a little time check my answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @bof, you added another that works for any  Polish space but I did not see anyone. Did you delete your post? or I lost it.

Comment: II had posted another answer, to which you commented, "I would recommend posting these nice answers as a new post." I'm not sure what you meant by that, but I deleted my secone answer and reposted it as an answer to a new question, here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4162677/partitioning-a-metric-space-into-cantor-sets

Comment: @bof, Oh, Thank you. I did not see this post. That's great.