# About ZFC and Partition perfect set into perfect sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, axioms, descriptive-set-theory

I was asking this question [Another way for partition of perfect set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4158663/707884) two days ago and there was a nice discussion over there but now I need to change the question by adding more conditions.

> - Question: Prove in ZFC that for any perfect  $P\subset\Bbb R$ there exists a family $\{P_{\alpha}\subset P\colon \alpha<\mathfrak c\}$, **none of them are a Cantor set** ,   of pairwise disjoint perfect subsets such that $$P=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mathfrak c} P_{\alpha}.$$ I know it is possible under CH, but quite sure in ZFC

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: What is the definition of "Cantor set" here?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I usually prefer this definition.  A set $A$ in a topological space $X$ is said to be a Cantor set if it is homeomorphic to, as a subspace of  $X$, to Cantor space $2^\omega.$

Comment: What if the perfect set $P$ happens to be the Cantor set itself? What's an example of a perfect set $P_\alpha\subset P$ which is not a Cantor set??

Comment: How do you know it's possible under CH?

Comment: If $P$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, then you can't possibly have an uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint perfect sets $P_\alpha\subset P$ which are not Cantor sets. Since $\mathbb R$ is separable, only countably many of the $P_\alpha$ can have nonempty interiors. The rest will be totally disconnected, compact, perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$, in other words, Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof, How do you know ? Reply: Please see this question, it was for $\Bbb R$ but I think it works for perfect as well.

Comment: @bof, I misunderstood your first question. I think, if you meant , $P$ is perfect set we could just ignore this case.

Comment: The Cantor set is a counterexample; it's a perfect set but it can't be partitioned into perfect sets which are not Cantor sets, because every perfect subset of the Cantor set is a Cantor set.

Comment: The following well-known classical result may be useful: any zero-dimensionsal compact metric space, which is nonempty and has no isolated points, is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126071/discussion-between-00gb-and-bof).

Answer (score 0):

@bof gave an  answer in one of his nice comments but I would like to make it clear by using the well-known fact:

**Fact**$1$. Every family $\mathcal U$ of pairwise disjoint of open subsets of $\Bbb R$ is at most countable.

By way of contradiction, let $P\subset\Bbb R$ be perfect set and $\{P_\alpha\subset P\colon \alpha<\mathfrak c\}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint perfect sets that are **NOT** Cantor set. This means that $P_{\alpha}^{\circ}\neq\emptyset$ for every $\alpha<\mathfrak c$, where $\circ$ denotes the interior set. Then, we have $$\{V_\alpha\subset P\colon \alpha<\mathfrak c\},$$ a family of pairwise disjoint open sets which is a contradiction with the **Fact $1$.**  This shows use we can not have a family of continuum many of pairwise disjoint perfect subsets that are not Cantor set.

Comment: bof, I add an answer the supports your idea. Thank you so much

Comment: You prove too much. In my comment I pointed out that a **bounded** subset of $\mathbb R$ can not contain uncountably many disjoint perfect sets which are not Cantor sets. That's because, if a (nonempty) perfect set $P\subseteq\mathbb R$ is not a Cantor set, it either has nonempty interior **or else it is unbounded**. If $C$ is the standard Cantor set, then $C+\mathbb Z=\{x+n:x\in C,\ n\in\mathbb Z\}$ is a perfect set but not a Cantor set, and it can be partitioned into $\mathfrak c$ disjoint perfect sets which are unbounded so they are not Cantor sets.

Comment: @bof, Yes, I meant **NOT**. I think I just mentioned  the well-known fact

Comment: @bof, I missed why $C+\Bbb Z$ is not a Cantor set.

Comment: By your definition in the comments, a Cantor set is homeomorphic to $2^\omega$, so a Cantor set must be compact. $C+\mathbb Z$ is not compact. A compact subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed and bounded. $C+\mathbb Z$ is a perfect set, it is closed, but it is unbounded.

Comment: @bof, Yes, you are right I missed that. This is not bounded.

Comment: So you need to correct your answer. Your claim "This means that $P_{\alpha}^{\circ}\neq\emptyset$" is incorrect since you have not assumed that the perfect set $P$ is bounded.

Comment: @bof, $P_\alpha ^{\circ}$ is not bounded, we can replace it with a subset of it which is bounded. since each perfect set contains a compact perfect subset.

Comment: So what? You claim (falsely) that "we can not have a family of continuum many of pairwise disjoint perfect subsets that are not Cantor set." But it is easy to construct continuum many disjoint perfect sets which are unbounded and therefore not Cantor sets. The fact that each of them contains a Cantor set is irrelevant, unless you weaken your claim to read "we can not have a family of continuum many of pairwise disjoint perfect subsets that **do not contain Cantor sets**. That of course is true, since every (nonempty) perfect set contains a Cantor set.